# jQuery: Target all except ___?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I'm looking for a way to select all elements on a page, except those with a specified DOM location.. Here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```
jQuery('*').except('.ignore').bind('click', function(e) { ... });
```

Is this possible in a "native jQuery" way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to use the [`:not()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not) selector:

```
jQuery(":not(.ignore)").bind("click", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Ah, I guess the asterisk in my example is probably redundant.

Comment: Now looking at it, I think I prefer without the asterisk.

Comment: hmmm, I wonder if $(':hover') works for elements that are in a hover state when it is called.

Answer (score 24):

Another way, if you already have selectors for both:

```
$('.foo').not('.ignore').bind(...);
```

Also, [more filters](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing).

Answer (score 8):

[jQuery not-selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector) to the rescue!

```
$('*:not(.ignore)').bind('click', function(e) { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, doing something to every element on a page simultaneous is nasty. There's a better way. I would recommend binding to the body then ignoring clicks on some elements:

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
    if($target.closest('.ignore').length) return true;
    ...
});
```

…Or using jQuery 1.3's [`.live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), which does this for you:

```
 $(":not(.ignore)").live(function(e){
    ...
});
```