# Select table cells w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I select all but the first TDs? I don't know how many columns there could be in the table, so I can't really use :nth-child(2) etc...

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>do not select</td>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>select</td>
    ...
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean `select all`?

Comment: Duplicate? Even after reading it I don't think so...

Comment: Not exact duplicate @Marek . Similars, yes, duplicates? no :)

Comment: @sennin sorry, this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467226/jquery-target-all-except

Comment: @Marek Sebera Isn't it the same URL? Still not the duplicate. In any case, why is -1?

Comment: @santa i wrote similar, not duplicate, that's is just chaining your and that questions together because the problem is similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using `:gt(0)` which select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```
$("table td:gt(0)");
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7yF/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
$allTableCellsButFirst = $('table tr td').not('tr:first-child td:first-child');
```

Should do the trick for you.

[**Working Example via jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/BVpdR/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr td:first-child').siblings();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to your TD's:

```
$('#someTable .tableCell').each(function()
{
    alert($(this).html());
});
```