# Select all elements except a div and its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Target all except ___?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467226/jquery-target-all-except)

I've got a script that detects clicks on every element on the page. I'd like that to run on everything except a specific div and its children.

I've tried doing this using the :not selector, but don't really understand how to use that effectively, so I'm not sure if that's the right way to go or not.

Here's some sample code:

```
<div id="clickme">This is good stuff</div>

<div id="dontclickme">This should not get selected</div>
```

I'm currently using `$("*")` for my selector. Is there a way to use that to detect if it's the second div, or any of its children?

Comment: event.target is what you will want. see: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to check if element has a certain id or element is a children/descendant of element with certain id...

```
$('body *').filter(function(i, v) {        
    return $(v).closest('#dontclickme').length == 0;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/7JE7x/

Answer (score 0):

Select all `div`s, but not `.class`:

```
$("div").not(".class")
```

Works with other selectors too.