# jQuery targeting with :not selector

Tags: jquery, targeting

I'm trying to get the html of an element except for one of its children.

I've tried this based on other questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467226/jquery-target-all-except)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535331/how-to-hide-all-elements-except-one-using-jquery) (etc), but the :not selected does not appear to work on my case.

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GyKr6/1/

In this case, this works as expected

```
$("#previewLink .toRemove").remove();
```

But I want the resulting html.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#previewLink").clone().find(".toRemove").remove().end().html();
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I've never used .end() before

Comment: @jose `.end()` is a little bit counter-intuitive at first but it's incredibly useful. If you envision a chain of jQuery calls as a stack, `.end()` pops the last "destructive" entry off that stack and restores the previous state. "Destructive" means "every operation that changes the list of selected elements", in this case `.find()`.