# JQuery Click for any child in any children except

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind an event for any `child` within any `children` in a `div` **except** for a specified `child` with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#holder").find('*').each(function(){


    if($(this).context.nodeName !== "SPAN"){
      $(this).click(function(){
        window.console.log('s');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

However, because the `SPAN` is within an element, the `click` event is still being called. Is there any way around this?

I have a demo [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pizun/1/edit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Target all except \_\_\_?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467226/jquery-target-all-except)

Comment: @ling.s the other solution doesn't work

Comment: check the value of `$(this).context.nodeName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `else` condition to negate the click if it is a span

```
if($(this).context.nodeName !== "SPAN"){
  $(this).click(function(){
    window.console.log('s');
  });
}
else {
  $(this).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // negate click
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put a click handler on all the `p` blocks.  The `span` is in one of the `p` blocks.  It gets the click event, but does nothing with it, it then bubbles up to the `p`.

You need to put a click handler on the `span` and then have it swallow the event.  By calling `event.stopPropagation()`.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: here is typo: `event.stopPropigation()` should be `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#holder").find('*').on('click', function(e){
     if($(e.target).is('span')){
        return;
     }else{
        console.log('s');
     }
  });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/huwebopi/1/edit)

---

Here we are finding all elements in `#holder` and binding the `click` event on every node except the `span`.

Comment: @NewAmbition Glad we helped you.

Comment: sorry - it seems as if it isn't working on my live environment. I just want to make 100% sure this is right :)

Comment: @NewAmbition okay be 100% sure with other answers too.

Answer (score 1):

What you encountered is known as `Event Bubble`. The children's event will be bubbled up to container when it is triggered, To read more about it . Please read [What is event bubble?](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm)

[What is the event.stopPropagation used for?](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `type` of event source and skip the event handler code when event source is `span`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/nipuzeko/2/edit)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  $("#holder *").click(function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName == 'SPAN') return;
    window.console.log('s');
  });      
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this out?

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code to stop propagating the event to the next level when span is clicked:

```
$("#holder span").click(function(event,v){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#holder").find('*').each(function(){

    if($(this).context.nodeName != 'SPAN')
    {
      $(this).click(function(e){
        window.console.log('s');
      });
   }
else
{
 $(this).click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation(); 
      });

}
  });

});
</script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="holder">
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>might say</p>
    <p>that being</p>
    <p>in <span annid="1" style="font-weight:bold">space</span></p>
    <p>is like</p>
    <p>communicating with</p>
    <p>dead pixels</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem in your code is beacuse of event propagation , the click event is propagating from the `<p>` event . This is beacuse , the `span` is inside the `<p>` element

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#holder").find("*:not(span)").on('click', function() { ... });
```